# NPM Error SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, nestjs

I'm trying to run my Next JS and NEST JS application. I got the code from my work but after I clone it and try to npm install, it shows error

```
19072:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677
```

I tried to find similar answer and all but I couldn't find the solution for my npm

```
NPM Version: 7.24.1
Node Version: 14.7.6
```

My co-workers are doing fine until now but I'm keep coding blindedly without even running the code. Is there any solution for this problem?

I've tried:

```
1. reinstalling node and npm
2. remove node_modules
3. npm install -g npm
4. npm clean cache --force
5. npm install
6. googling and searching for solution in stack overflow
```

I found out that python is involved too..i think, my `python version: 3.8.3`

Comment: I am facing similar issue, did you get any solution?

Comment: Had you found any solution? having same problem on windows

Comment: most probably, issue with your network, try the same on some another network/wifi